# How to bind a binding from the parent view to the ViewModel of the subview?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I'm currently having a problem how to bind a Binding from the parent view to a Published in the ViewModel of the DetailView.

I constructed a short example which indicates my problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List($viewModel.items, id: \.wrappedValue) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                Text(item.wrappedValue)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items: [String] = []
    
    func loadItems() async {
        print("get items from server")
    }
    
    // do a lot more stuff here
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: DetailViewModel
                
    init(item: Binding<String>) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: DetailViewModel(item: item))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.item)
    }
}

class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var item: String

    // more published vars from more network calls
    
    init(item: Binding<String>) {
        self._item = Published(wrappedValue: item.wrappedValue)  // losing the two-way binding at this point -> changing the item here does not update the item in the parent view
    }
    
    // do a lot more stuff with the item here, e.g. network calls
}
```

The problem is that the ContentView does not update when I change the item in the DetailViewModel.

I know one possible solution would be to hold the item Binding in the DetailView, instead of passing it to the DetailViewModel. However this approach seems wrong to me since that way I have variables, which are used by the view, in multiple places (some in viewModel and some in View). Also I always need to pass the item to the viewModel for function calls and the item can't be manipulated from the logic within the viewModel.

Do I miss something or is my approach completely off?

Comment: Your setup is somewhat convoluted. Have you tried `List($viewModel.items, id: \.self) { $item in
 NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: $item)) ...`, note the two `$item`. I don't really see why you need to have binding all over.

Comment: The problem is not that the code does not compile, it does. It's rather that the parent view does not update when I change the item in the DetailViewModel.

Comment: Binding is only for SwiftUI views and View Models should never know about each other. You should rethink your approach one option is to add another layer such as a manager that holds shared data o

Answer (score 1):

Remove the legacy view model object (In SwiftUI the `View` struct plus state is equivalent). Use `let` for read access or `@Binding` for write access, e.g.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    let item: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

`body` will be called automatically when a `let` (if it is used in `body`) or `@Binding var` changes. You don't get this dependency tracking behaviour if you try to use view model objects.

Comment: So you would put all the logic into the view itself? I have multiple network calls and handle logic which additionally needs to be applied.

Comment: Yes, because the `View` struct is not "the view" it is just view data that SwiftUI uses to create/update/remove `UIView` objects automatically. Use `.task(id:)` for network calls.